# UPDATE ... FROM different column depending on a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have prepared a simple [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b7252/5) for my question.

In PostgreSQL 10 user ids are stored in `words_users` table, but their names are stored in `words_social` table:

```
CREATE TABLE words_users (
        uid     SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE words_social (
        sid     text     NOT NULL,
        social  integer  NOT NULL CHECK (0 < social AND social <= 64),
        given   text     NOT NULL CHECK (given ~ '\S'),
        uid     integer  NOT NULL REFERENCES words_users ON DELETE CASCADE,
        PRIMARY KEY(sid, social)
);

INSERT INTO words_users (uid) VALUES (1), (2);

INSERT INTO words_social (sid, social, given, uid) VALUES 
('1111', 10, 'Alice', 1), 
('2222', 20, 'Bob', 2);
```

Two-player games are stored in the following table, with `chat1` and `chat2` columns holding number of new chat messages for `player1` or `player2` (here Alice and Bob both have 1 new message waiting in the game #100):

```
CREATE TABLE words_games (
        gid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        player1 integer REFERENCES words_users(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL CHECK (player1 <> player2),
        player2 integer REFERENCES words_users(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE,
        chat1 integer NOT NULL,
        chat2 integer NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO words_games (gid, player1, player2, chat1, chat2) 
VALUES (100, 1, 2, 1, 1);
```

When a user reads her chat messages, I would like to reset the corresponding column (`chat1` or `chat2`) back to 0.

And I can not use `uid` to identify the user, I have to go via `sid` and `social`.

So I am trying to reset the number of new chat messages for Bob in game #100:

```
UPDATE words_games g
SET    CASE WHEN s.uid = g.player1 THEN chat2 = 0 ELSE chat1 = 0 END
FROM   words_social s
WHERE  g.gid    = 100
AND    s.social = 20
AND    s.sid    = '2222'
AND    s.uid IN (g.player1, g.player2);
```

but get a syntax error, because `CASE` is not allowed there.

Does anybody please have a good suggestion here?

The background of my question is that I have already [a working stored function in pl/pgSQL](https://gist.github.com/afarber/776fd772e71f44c96b7758916c6542cd) but would like to switch to pure SQL for better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with two separate `set` clauses:

```
UPDATE word_games g
    SET chat2 = (CASE WHEN s.uid = g.player1 THEN 0 ELSE chat2 END),
        chat1 = (CASE WHEN s.uid = g.player1 THEN chat1 ELSE 0 END)
    . . .
```